# Автотест Руби не запускается. Кaк найти папку чтобы закинуть Хромдрайвер

Tags: ruby, test-automation

Добрый день, прошу помощи. Как я понял из логов, что моей программе не хватает прописать путь к Хромдрайверу. Я не могу найти папку в которую необходимо закинуть сам файл Хромдрайвер.

Сам Автотест:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit
puts driver.title
driver.quit
```

Логи:

> /usr/local/bin/ruby -e
>   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
>   /home/vt/RubymineProjects/untitled2/Automation/Steps_Automation/Opensites.rb
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in
>   `assert_ok': unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision:
>   2a03c99a5f45c6d507af8eb2345ad68a565d1518
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.8.0-51-generic x86_64)

[image: Моя программа]

Comment: Рекомендую тестить на Firefox, пока не научитесь, а потом уже браться за Chrome, потому что для Firefox драйвер не нужен, поэтому работает с пол-пинка.

Answer (score 0):

На Windows, если Path не указывать, можно вот так

```
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\ProgramFiles\Webdriver\Chrome\chromedriver.exe'
```